# Javascript - event is triggered when added

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onclicklistener

I'm trying to add an EventListener to all Input Elements constantly.

But when I add the EventListener the function is triggered.

```
window.onload = window.setInterval(function () {
    var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("FRAME");
    for (var i = 0; i < frame.length; i++) {
        frame_doc = frame[i].contentWindow.document || frame[i].contentDocument;
        var elem = frame_doc.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        for (var j = 0; j < elem.length; j++)
            if (elem[i]) {
                alert(true);
                //if(typeof elem[i].onclick === "function") 
                //removeEvent(elem[i], "click", check());
                addEvent(elem[i], "click", check());
            }
    }
}, 50);

function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function () {
            return (fn.call(elem, window.event));
        });
    }
}

function check() {
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling the function when binding the event on new element.
When you use `check()` when binding the event, the function `check` is called. You can remove the `()` of the `check`

```
addEvent(elem[i], "click", check());
```

Should be

```
addEvent(elem[i], "click", check); // removed () of check
```